# Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "No authorization code"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

Im trying to set up Facebook login on my app with devise...however I have run into a problem.

The site redirects the user to Facebook then says:

"Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

It returns to app and says:

Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "No authorization code".

Here is my code, Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        end
      end
    end
```

My devise.rb:

```
      config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],
      scope: 'email, public_profile', info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name'
```

routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

    authenticated :user do
        root 'home#index', as: 'authenticated_root'
      end

      devise_scope :user do
        root 'devise/sessions#new'
      end

    end
```

My omniauth controller:

```
    class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

      def facebook
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        sign_in_and_redirect @user
      end
    end
```

Thanks

I will add I'm running this on local host and in the developer section on Facebook I have added 'http://localhost:3000/' in the app domain section.

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook console in the top left corner, click on your app name then create a test app for your website.

Then replace your main Facebook secret keys with the test keys.

Also make sure your 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' is set to

http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback

This Is what sorted for me.

Good luck

Comment: please give use more details about your fix, you will earn points in the future for this solution, because this is a very common issue with many other developers

Comment: Sure I'm away from my computer at the moment, I will update in a couple of hours